# git init & templates not being found

Tags: git

I'm attempting to use git templates, so I can have a few pre-defined hooks on all repos I have locally. When I attempt to run `git init`, however, it doesn't find the templates in the directory. This isn't true if I specify it through other means.

```bash
[nix-shell:~/tmp/ai-webui/foo]$ git config --global init.templateDir
'/home/abrahms/.git_template/'

[nix-shell:~/tmp/ai-webui/foo]$ git init
warning: templates not found in '/home/abrahms/.git_template/'
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/abrahms/tmp/ai-webui/foo/.git/

[nix-shell:~/tmp/ai-webui/foo]$ git init --template=/home/abrahms/.git_template/
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/abrahms/tmp/ai-webui/foo/.git/

[nix-shell:~/tmp/ai-webui/foo]$ export GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR="$HOME/.git_template/"

[nix-shell:~/tmp/ai-webui/foo]$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/abrahms/tmp/ai-webui/foo/.git/

[nix-shell:~/tmp/ai-webui/foo]$ unset GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR

[nix-shell:~/tmp/ai-webui/foo]$ git init
warning: templates not found in '/home/abrahms/.git_template/'
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/abrahms/tmp/ai-webui/foo/.git/

[nix-shell:~/tmp/ai-webui/foo]$ git --version
git version 2.40.1
```

I'd expect the bar `git init` to work just like specifying the envvar or `--template` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've over-quoted the value of `init.templateDir`. You shouldn't see those single quotes in the output. For example, if I run:

```
git config --global init.templateDir ~/.config/git/templates
```

And then run:

```
git config --global init.templateDir
```

I see as output:

```
/home/lars/.config/git/templates
```

Not (as you show in your question):

```
'/home/lars/.config/git/templates'
```

In my global git config, I see:

```
[init]
    templateDir = /home/lars/.config/git/templates
```